# How to factor the polynomial $8x^3-16x-85$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, cubics

While solving a problem on sequences and series, I got the following cubic equation

$$8x^3-16x-85=0$$

I cannot figure out how to solve it. I have tried to factor the L.H.S., but did not succeed. Please  help. Are these type of equations solvable by factorization or is using a particular formula the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Find a rational zero $p/q$ such that $p$ divides $85$ and $q$ divides $8$. Note also that $f(2)=-53<0$ and $f(3)=83>0$.

Comment: Is there any general rule that helps in factorizing polynomials like these?

Comment: No a general rules, but the following criterion is useful: if a polynomial $P(x)=a_nx^n+\dots a_0\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ has a rational root $p/q$ then $p$ divides $a_0$ and $q$ divides $a_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Assume that $8x^3-16x-85=(ax+b)(cx^2+dx+f)$ and compare coefficients. Then we see that
$$
8x^3-16x-85=(2x-5)(4x^2+10x+17).
$$